# Subir archivos con php y asignarlos a un ID especifico de una tabla con el fin de que este pueda ser luego descargado

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera agregar a mi sistema la opción de subir archivos, pero que estos se conecten o se guarden en base a un registro de la tabla `PROYECTO`, que cuando se abra determinado proyecto en una lista se puede bajar su archivo digital.

es decir:
Proyecto de luz solar, ID 5, proy.doc
Desarrollo de sistema social, ID 7, proy2.pdf

He buscado varias formas pero no he podido realizarlo.

Conseguí este código para subir archivos pero no se como realizar la conexión a la base de datos para que se guarden allí y luego pueda sacarlos seleccionando el ID de cualquiera de los proyectos.

Agrego además, que no se si es necesario crear un registro en la base de datos para guardar el archivo, porque el código solo los guarda en el directorio que coloque.

CÓDIGO DE SUBIDA:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Quisiera además restringir el tipo solo para documentos doc, docx, y pdf. Cómo podría hacerlo?

CODIGO PARA AGREGAR, En repuesta a los comentarios:

```
function bd_documento_agregar($d){
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO dcumento (docu_id, proy_id) 
     VALUES ('%s','%s')",
     $d['docu_id'],
    $d['proy_id']);
$res = sql($sql);
$id  = sql2value("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para saber el tipo del archivo subido, puedes usar `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"]` y solo tendrías que añadir una condición mas al código

```
// Allow certain file formats
$FileType = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"];
if($FileType != "doc" && $FileType != "docx" && $FileType != "pdf") {
    echo "Formato no Admitido. Solo formatos DOC, DOCX y PDF.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Aunque también podrías hacer una validación en el formulario por `javascript` para evitar enviar el formulario si el tipo de documento no es el que deseas.

**EDITADO**

Para asociar el documento a un proyecto tienes al menos estas tres opciones.

- Crear una tabla de documentos, y otra tabla llamada
  documentos-proyectos, de esta manera en la tabla documentos guardas
  la info del fichero subido y en la tabla documentos-proyectos,
  guardas la relación entre el proyecto y los documentos. Esta opción
  seria para casos en los que los proyectos compartan documentos.
- Crear una tabla documentos, en la que un campo sea `idproyecto`, y a
  la hora de subir el documento hacer un `INSERT` en esta nueva tabla.
  Esta opción sería válida en caso de que los documentos no se pudiesen
  compartir en otros proyectos.
- Dentro de la tabla proyectos, crear un campo `documento`, que guarde
  el nombre del documento subido, lo que te obligaría a subir un único
  fichero por poyecto y con nombres distitntos

Cualquiera de las opciones que consideres la deberías codificar en esta parte del código

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
       //***************************************************************
       //         INSERTAR AQUI EL CÓDIGO
       //***************************************************************
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

Comment: Esto ayudaria mucho para el tipo de documento, ahora faltaria como relacionarlo con un ID

Comment: http://blog.kiuvox.com/2016/02/23/como-guardar-archivos-en-mysql-desde-php/ podria adaptar este tutorial a mi necesidad?

Comment: El ID, al que quieres asignar la foto, a que pertenece?. No es lo mismo que quieras hacer una galería de imagenes, que asociar una imagen a un prodructo, por ejmeplo.

Comment: tengo una tabla proyecto la cual almacena los proyectos de estudiantes, este tiene un ID, quisiera que los archivos que suba sele asignen al ID de determinado trabajo.

Id 6 proyecto de suma y reste, proyecto20015.docx:

para que se pueda con una opcion de VER TRABAJO descargar su digital

Comment: He editado mi contestación para tener la respuesta completa

Comment: supongo que seria la 3ra opcion o la 2da?. ya que cada proyecto tendria un documento, y no deberia compartilo con otros, una duda seria si subo un proyecto el 25 de enero, y el 26 quiero subir la correcion lo sustituiria?, o eso debo configurarlo en

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

Comment: Yo optaría por la tercera opción. En cuanto al tema de sustituir es algo peligroso, porque si al subir un documento lo subes con el mismo nombre, de otro existente, se podría liar gorda. Lo que yo hago, renombro siempre los ficheros para evitar que se puedan duplicar los nombres, y guardar siempre el último nombre guardado. Aunque se puede crear una funcion para borrar el fichero.

Comment: Si esto te preocupa seriamente, mejor la opción 2, renombrando los ficheros que subas y mostar siempre el último fichero asociado a un proyecto, mediante un LIMIT 1 ORDER BY ID desc

Comment: Tambien optare por la 3ra opcion, ya cree la tabla con docu_id, proy_id y nomb_docu.

Sobre lo de sustituir, no hacerlo, quisiera si seria posible que cada proyecto se le asignara varios documentos, seria mejor para así poder guardar las correcciones, como también mostrar solo el ultimo. como dices de la opcion LIMIT 1 ORDER BY ID. Se le podria pedir a la persona que subira el archivo que le coloque un nombre clave no se, y luego al subirlo que no sea igual al anterior.

Comment: Publicare un formulario que tengo, que muestra en una lista desplegable los proyectos, y con su respectivo codigo para guardar. 

No se si este funcione, ya que lo uso guardando datos con checkbox tomando el ID del proyecto, funcionaria esto para lo que quiero hacer?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45278/discussion-between-jose-javier-segura-and-victor-alejandro-alvarado-vilo).